# Not understanding 'Possible leak of an object' error

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, memory-leaks

```
346 - NSFileManager *fileManager = [[NSFileManager alloc] init];
347 - [fileManager removeItemAtPath:[mediaSource.newMediaToDelete objectAtIndex:i] error:nil];
348 - [fileManager release];
```

The error points towards line 348 and says:

> 'Potential leak of an object allocated on line 347'

I don't understand this, obviously line 347 isn't an allocation, and the allocation on line 346 is already released.

Comment: I think there is no problem with the `NSFileManager`. I think  the problem is in the getter of `newMediaToDelete` which maybe returns a not autoreleased object. Can you post some code of the getter or the corresponding property

Comment: If you haven’t changed the getter name, the compiler/analyser thinks that `-newMediaToDelete` returns an owned object because its name starts with ‘new’.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Avoid using the 'new' or 'create' in your own method names (unless they return objects that are not autoreleased I guess). It confuses the static analyser. I've had this issue and found it went away when I changed my method name.

Update: I see Bavarious has already noted this in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

May be in NSArray mediaSource.newMediaToDelete objects are not autorelease?

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following code and did not get any warning:

```
  NSInteger i = 0;
    NSArray *ax = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"a",@"b",@"c",nil];
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [[NSFileManager alloc] init];
    [fileManager removeItemAtPath:[ax objectAtIndex:i] error:nil];
    [fileManager release];
```

So it must be with returned mediaSource.newMediaToDelete object...

try a var assignemnt like:

```
x = [mediaSource.newMediaToDelete objectAtIndex:i];
```

and it should show there...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to click on the error message itself? Those arrows which show you the path of your problem are sometimes very useful. I guess it is the mediaSource or newmediaToDelete object which causes the message.